# Attempt to mutate immutable object with appendFormat

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Hii i am doing a calculator on iphone when i clear the mutable string and try to add another value to it 
it says that Attempt to mutate immutable object with appendFormat
what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

Please alloc the NSMutableString before adding the another value.

Comment: Ok but i have allocated it in Viewdidload method             - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
 
 numberString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:1];